# heroku deploy fails with fog-aws (says formatador "removed")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fog-aws

I have a web site uploading images to AWS using the fog-aws gem. Everything works fine when I run it locally, but it will not deploy to heroku. Standard heroku/ruby buildpack, latest versions of everything:

ruby 2.5.1, rails 5.2.2, 
gem 'carrierwave', '1.3.1'
gem 'fog-aws', '3.3.0'

Tried:
1) Of course, deleting the Gemfile.lock file and bundle installing several times
2) Explicitly including formatador, using older versions (I don't think the error message is correct, since formatador 0.2.5 does exist and I can install it both locally and on heroku)
3) Using 'fog' instead of 'fog-aws' (gives me similar errors with 'unf', and includes a ton of unnecessary dependencies)

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Your bundle is locked to formatador (0.2.5), but that version could not be found
remote:        in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources,
remote:        that means the author of formatador (0.2.5) has removed it. You'll need to
remote:        update your bundle to a different version of formatador (0.2.5) that hasn't been
remote:        removed in order to install.
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Your bundle is locked to formatador (0.2.5), but that version could not be found
remote:        in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources,
remote:        that means the author of formatador (0.2.5) has removed it. You'll need to
remote:        update your bundle to a different version of formatador (0.2.5) that hasn't been
remote:        removed in order to install.
```

Comment: maybe post the gemfile too.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out; just needed to RTFM!

I needed a "require 'fog/aws'" at the top of config/initializers/fog.rb. Worked locally without it, but caused the behavior above when deployed to heroku. I added that line, and it worked.